# Exchange filename position

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I want to exchange hundreds of filename positions of a file in FolderX.

The file names are all created on this way: pos1.pos2.pos3.pos4.pos5.pos6.pdf
example: (GK.19.kkla.0715.nr.36053342.zg.119.pdf)

I would like to exchange some positions so that it changes to: pos4.pos2.pos5.pos6.pos3.pos1.pdf

As an example, a command such as; exchange pos3->pos6 or pos1->pos4

I looked in the Automator, but it can only add before or after file names, but no positions exchange.

maybe AppleScript? Thanks for inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution uses AppleScript's text item delimiters and System Events. It is quite fast, and has the advantage of avoiding throwing an error when the filename of some file in a folder does not match the desired pattern. Also, it works with pdfs of the folder.

```
set folderHFS to (choose folder) as text

set {ATID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, "."}
tell application "System Events"
    repeat with aFile in (get files of folder folderHFS whose name extension is "pdf")
        try
            set {pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, pos5, pos6, ext} to text items of (get name of aFile)
            set name of aFile to {pos4, pos2, pos5, pos6, pos3, pos1, ext} as text
        end try
    end repeat
end tell
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ATID
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. 1. Easy to use. |  2. it works with varios extensions ( pdf,txt,jpg) | 3. As output i write just 4 that i need, and it WORKS - Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: is it possible to make variable positions of different lengths as input of positions? as an example; some of input files have 6 positions some of them have 9 positions. for the output file i can choose 2 or 3 positons that i need but input must be exact number of positions?

Comment: One thought would be to put it into a handler and instead of hard coding the text items, provide a pair of indexes to swap in the arguments.

Comment: red_manace; and how to do that? can u show me exemple, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use AppleScript (scripting Finder/System Events to traverse the files and text item delimiters to split up each file name), or you could do it with a shell script, which has the advantage of being much quicker:

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in /path/to/input/folder/*; do
    n=`basename "$f" | awk -F '.' '{ print $4"."$2"."$5"."$6"."$3"."$1".pdf" }'`
    mv "$f" "/path/to/output/folder/$n"
done
```

Comment: Works fine, i must little change it to avoid manual writing every time Source and Output folder (i Just make; (for f in "${@}" do....) its ok but on end he search still output-folder and with command ${@/n} don't work, thanks a lot for input